# DNS resolution in aws from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ping, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

If spinned up an EC2 instance in a vpc, I removed all outbound rules for security group of EC2, when I ping any public domain like google.com, Facebook.Com from server, still its getting the ip address of domain(similarly pinging Google.com {ipaddress} with 32 bytes of data). From where does instance gets ip address of domain and on which port? even though I blocked all outbound rules of security group?

Answer (score 3):

AWS security groups and network ACLs don't filter traffic to or from:

- AWS reserved IPv4 addresses (these are the first four IPv4 addresses of the subnet, including the Amazon DNS server address for the VPC)
- link-local addresses (169.254.0.0/16)

The Amazon-supplied VPC DNS server is at the VPC subnet CIDR base +2 address (e.g. 10.0.0.2 if your VPC subnet CIDR is 10.0.0.0).

See [Internetwork traffic privacy in Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Security.html#VPC_Security_Comparison).